# Relatively prime numbers and probability.

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let's assume **p1** and **p2** are even numbers(**p1≠p2**) and **gcd(p1,m)=1**, **gcd(p2,m)=1**, where **m** is a positive integer, prove that there exist infinitely many **m** so that **gcd(p1+m,p2+m)=1**.

**m,m^2,...,m^k** are natural numbers, where m is randomly chosen natural number so that **gcd(p1,m)=1**, **gcd(p2,m)=1**. Prove that for sufficiently big k probability of **gcd(p1+m^n,p2+m^n)=1** is bigger than **gcd(p1+m^n,p2+m^n)>1**,where n = 1,2,3...k.

Comment: I cannot discern any probability distribution.

Comment: What I wrote was wrong, I fixed it.

Comment: Could you please clarify what function (I presume) gcd is?

Comment: @Easymode44 gcd is greatest common divisor, also called hcf (highest common factor). Essentially, gcd$(x,y)=1$ means $x$ and $y$ are coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Given $p_1,p_2\in \Bbb N$ with $p_1<p_2$ and given any $n\in \Bbb N,$ we can find $m>n$ such that $m+p_1,m+p_2$ are co-prime, as follows:

Let  $p$ be prime with $p>p_1+n$ and $p>p_2-p_1.$ Let $m=p-p_1$.

Then  $m=p-p_1>(p_1+n)-p_1=n.$

Now $p_2+m>p_1+m=p,$ but the prime $p$ does not divide $p_2+m$ because $$1< \frac {p_2+m}{p}=\frac {(p_2-p_1)+p}{p}<\frac {p +p}{p}=2.$$

Therefore $\gcd(p_1+m, p_2+m)=\gcd (p,p_2+m)=1.$